# How to bypass or add authentication for git scripts in Bamboo

Tags: git, batch-file, bamboo

I need to run a simple batch script that pulls an external git repository within a bamboo workflow. The batch script works fine anywhere in my computer but when I run it in bamboo it hangs. When I first ran the script in the command prompt on our test server it asked for some login authentication so I suspect it is related to this. Does anyone have any experience solving this or know if it is a separate issue? Unfortunately using bamboo itself to pull this repository is causing unexplained errors in my automated test that only happen in bamboo.

```
cd PATH/TO/MY/REPO
git pull
```

Comment: You can try generating SSH access key for your repository and place it on Bamboo Agent. This way it should be able to authenticate using your key and not asking for password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used for pulling an external git repository using a batch script was adding my Git executable in the Server Capabilities. Previously I did not have this set up.

1. Go to *BAMBOO_BASEURL*/admin/administer.action
2. Click the Server Capabilities link under Build Resources
3. At the Add capability form
   select the following:

   a. Capability type : Git
     b. Executable: Git
     c. Path: C:\Program Files/Git/bin/git.exe (What i added for windows)
     d. Click the add button.
4. Then you can retry your script that runs git commands like `git pull`